# useStates seem as undefined on props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get some datas from child to parent. There is a way I usually do, and it totally works. But for one page I used:

```
 <Link to={{
            pathname: `/productBuy`,
            state: { product, iconClick }
          }}>
```

and when I send another prop from App.js to productBuy page, it's shown under product and it's undefined.

Codes from App.js :

```
const [productInformation, setProductInformation] = useState([]);
<Route path="/productBuy" render={props => <ProductBuy {...props} productInformation {productInformation} setProductInformation={setProductInformation} />} />
```

productBuy.js :

```
const ProductBuy = (productInfo, {productInformation,setProductInformation}) => {


    return ( 
        <div className="productBuy">
            <div className="productBuyContainer">
                <ProductLeft productInfo={productInfo.location.state} />
                <ProductRight productInfo={productInfo.location.state} productInformation={productInformation} setProductInformation={setProductInformation}/>
            </div>
        </div>
     );

}
```

When I console.log, my props are shown under product object as undefined. and when I invoke a function, an error appears: ProductRight.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: setProductInformation is not a function

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: `productInformation` and `setProductInformation` are available in the component props, which is the first argument of the component function. You're destructing them from the second argument, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you're missing the `=` after `productInformation` in the render prop:

```
<ProductBuy {...props} productInformation={productInformation} setProductInformation={setProductInformation} />
```

And the second issue is that you're unpacking the props incorrectly. Both `productInformation` and `setProductInformation` are available in the `props` argument (the first positional argument) in your function, but you're unpacking it in the second argument instead:

```
// INCORRECT
const ProductBuy = (productInfo, {productInformation,setProductInformation}) => { ... }
```

You can unpack it from the `productInfo` argument, which is an object that holds all the props:

```
const ProductBuy = (productInfo) => {
    const { productInformation, setProductInformation } = productInfo;
    return ( 
        <div className="productBuy">
            <div className="productBuyContainer">
                <ProductLeft productInfo={productInfo.location.state} />
                <ProductRight productInfo={productInfo.location.state} productInformation={productInformation} setProductInformation={setProductInformation}/>
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}
```

You can also choose to unpack it at the top level:

```
const ProductBuy = ({ location, productInformation, setProductInformation }) => {
    return ( 
        <div className="productBuy">
            <div className="productBuyContainer">
                <ProductLeft productInfo={location.state} />
                <ProductRight productInfo={location.state} productInformation={productInformation} setProductInformation={setProductInformation}/>
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}
```

Comment: it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @OzanBilgiç Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add equal sign when passing the `productInformation` to props seems you forgot that in `App.js`

```
<Route path="/productBuy" render={props => <ProductBuy {...props} productInformation={productInformation} setProductInformation={setProductInformation} />} />
```